# Calculating the price of a call and put using multinomial trees and risk-neutral probabilities

Tags: binomial-tree, self-study

I am self-studying for an actuarial exam and I encountered this example. The books shows one method of solving using a replicating portfolio, and then shows this solution involving risk-neutral probabilities.

My question is - I do not understand where the equations highlighted in red come from.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think they have expanded the third term on the LHS and simplified.